# g++ preprocessor define still listed as an undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have added a g++ preprocessor define for a variable called `DATA_CACHE_LOCATION` as such:

```
g++-4.8 -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wall -Weffc++ -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage file1.c++ file2.c++ -o file -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread -lboost_serialization -DDATA_CACHE_LOCATION="\"/a/b/c/d.bin\""
```

However, when attempting to run some tests, I run into the error:

```
file1.c++:50:41: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'DATA_CACHE_LOCATION'
  DataCache data_cache = get_data_cache(DATA_CACHE_LOCATION);
```

Why would this be an undeclared identifier when I have defined it using a preprocessor macro?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Can you perhaps create a [mcve] with an online compiler, and then link it here?

Comment: Of course, I do not have the same code as you, but it seems to be working fine for me (g++ 6.2.1). You might want to look if you have some hidden characters somewhere, or try with a newer version.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you move the `-DDATA_CACHE_LOCATION="\"/a/b/c` earlier in the commandline (like before the file(s) being compiled)?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Considering the difficulty in reproducing, I instead conditionally symlinked the cache file into the current directory using a shell script in the `makefile`.